# How do I specify the header location building gcc-12 on Macos M1?

Tags: macos, gcc

All.

I am trying to build gcc-12 on an M1 Mini running MacOS 11.3.1 with Xcode 13.2.1 using Ian's wonderful work at https://github.com/iains/gcc-darwin-arm64 but I cannot seem to specify the correct location for the include files. The following option is passed via configure:

```
--with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1
```

But the build process tries to look into `/usr/include` when it tries to fix includes.

Running `configure` without specifying the directory fails in the same manner.

P.S. I first posted this to *Ask Different* but received no response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this might work...

`../configure --prefix=$(pwd)/install --enable-languages=all --with-sysroot=$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)`